# Keystroke events using hidapi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, usb, keystroke, hidapi

I need to receive keystroke events from HID joystick. I opened the device using the hid_open() from hidapi, but I cannot get events when I press a key. Could you give me any idea?

Comment: hid_read() returns the error "Access is denied"

Answer (score 0):

May I ask if you want to use `hdi_read()` to read keyboard messages? If so, I'm afraid this operation won't work. Because you couldn't read or write reports from or to keyboards and mice on Windows. The OS won't allow it. You could refer to this [link](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/issues/336) for more information.